# Could I get the explicit solution to the following problem relate to generalized rayleigh quotient?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

$\bf x$ and $\bf a$  are complex vectors, $\bf C$ is positive definite complex matrix, $\bf B$ is positive-semidefinite complex matrix. What's the objective value? Thanks!

$$\max_{\bf x} \frac{\mathbf{x}^{H} \mathbf{a a}^{H}\mathbf x}{1+\bf x^{H}Bx}$$
$$ {\rm s.t.  } ~~ {\mathbf{x}^{H} \mathbf{Cx} } \leq P$$

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant solution to your problem, involving the principle eigenvector. You find a similar problem with its solution in http://www.fhp.tu-darmstadt.de/nt/fileadmin/nas/Publications/2010/Filter-and-Forward...chen.pdf

In this paper, consider problem (43) with the solution given by (47).

Comment: Plz vote up :-)